# Does Azure have a sandbox for App Service Domain and SSL testing?

Tags: c#, azure, sandbox, azure-fluent-api

I am currently using [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.fluent?view=azure-dotnet) and direct RESTApi calls to automate some of my application deployment on Azure.

Prior to now, whenever I have needed to test some API I was able to use my production environment and simply spin up a VM or webapp etc because the marginal cost of doing so was effectively nil. It never really occurred to me to see if Azure has some sort of sandbox.

However I am currently in the process of integration of the issuance of domain names and ssl certificates into our application, each of these invocations are immediately billed and in the case of an ssl certificate the cost is nearly $100 in Australia.

So say I want to do this

```
var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
.Configure()
.WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
.Authenticate(credentials)
.WithDefaultSubscription();

var createdSSL = await azure.AppServices.AppServiceCertificates
.Define("MyNewDomain")
.WithRegion(Region.AustraliaSouthEast)
.WithExistingResourceGroup("MyResourceGroup")
.WithPfxFileFromUrl("myurl.com")
.WithPfxPassword("mypassword")
.CreateAsync();
```

[Based on current pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) this means that if I want to just run a single test of domain name invocation and ssl issuance its going to cost ~$120 which is obviously undesirable.

So does Azure provide some way to test immediately billable API invocations without charging? Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Maybe there is a solution with the [DeploymentWhatIfProperties](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/07ece241182fea976cfbcd0882f3dc122e9baa1c/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Generated/Models/DeploymentWhatIfProperties.cs), but I didn't verify that

Comment: One workaround would be to use your own certificate authority to issue the TLS cert (just issue  and re-use same cert for testing only), and adjust test client to trust that specific cert or authority.

Answer (score 2):

You might try with free App Service Plan for SSL Testing. Please have a look

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/secure-your-custom-domains-at-no-cost-with-app-service-managed-certificates-preview/

Free Certificate for Apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-certificate-preview

Comment: Thanks mate, unfortunately free azure certificates for web apps only works for non apex domains. I am awarding you the points since no one else has provided a better answer but I wont mark your question as the answer given it doesn't actually resolve the root problem.

Comment: Thanks for award and details as well!! ☺️